# gap appearing between table-cell-display divs after zooming

Tags: html, css

I am experiencing a very unusual bug with chrome. basically, I have 2 div's with table-cell displays. One has text in it the other an input. What happens is when the page is zoomed in and then zoomed out again. a gap appears between the top of the input and the top border, and each time the page is zoomed in and out the gap gets bigger and bigger. If both div's have only text or both have inputs, then it's OK.setting the divs height makes no difference. No such problem with FF. here is a little diagram to illustrate.

It start's like this:

```
                .--------.--------.                
                .  text  . |input|. 
                .--------.--------.
```

after zooming in and out sereral times, it looks like this:

```
                . -------.--------.                
                .        .        .
                .        .        . 
                .  text  . |input|. 
                .--------.--------.
```

here is the code:

```
.border{
         border:1px solid grey; 
         display:table-cell;
       }

      <div class = "border">text</div>
      <div class = "border"><input /></div>
```

does anyone have any idea why this might be happening, and what can be done to prevent it? Thanks.

Comment: could you provide a basic fiddle reproducing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this, it will help you...

```
  .border
   {
     border:1px solid grey;
     display:table-cell;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle
   }
```